# GridView issues ASP.NET / ADO Entities

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am fairly new to working with ASP controls. I am having some issues with a project. This project is fairly large and my team has placed the ADO.NET emtity inside the same solution but placed into a different project inside Visual Studio 2010. The original db was built through SQL Server 2008.  I was wondering if it would be possible to connect a GridView control to this entity in order to show certain aspects of it?

Also, If not possible, we have a class Customer which has certain members (name, dob, ssn,...etc) and functions that will pull these customers from the db through the ADO.NET. Could I populate the GridView with a a list of instances of this class?

something like

```
List<Customers> CustList = new List<Customers>();
....populate the list.....
Gridview.DataSource = CustList;
Gridbiew.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can! Just add a reference the other project from the one that has the GridView, and set the DataSource property of the GridView to the entity that is in the other project. Indeed, this is a common design in applications, to separate them by "layers"(also criticised a lot).
Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and tried it. I added a reference (to the Entity inside the other project) in the same project that my GridView is located. However, when I select EntityDataSource as my data source for the gridview, it doesn't seem to find the AIA-Entities to select from.

Comment: #Shenn, I recommend you to take a look at links like this http://www.webanddesigners.com/tiered-architecture-in-cnet-dataaccess-business-ui-entity/ to have a better understanding. If I had more info about your project, I could help a little bit more. Good luck!